# Check if for a patient the next admission date is less than previous discharge then make the admission date equal to previous discharge

Tags: r

I got data with patient admission and discharge dates but some patients have for example for their second admission the date of admission is less than the first discharge. I want check and where the subsequent admission date is less than the previous discharge to make them equal. This is the data

```
structure(list(id = c(1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4), adm = c("2014/08/29", 
"2006/06/14", "2006/08/23", "2007/01/01", "2007/01/03", "2005/07/02"
), disc = c("2014/09/08", "2006/08/31", "2006/08/31", "2007/01/07", 
"2007/01/08", "2005/07/03")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-6L))
```

I get data like this when us on my original data which I can't share but it works on this sample data.

```
    df <- data %>% group_by(id) %>% 
  mutate(across(c(adm, disc), as.Date)) %>% 
  mutate(adm = if_else(adm < lag(disc, default = first(adm)), lag(disc), adm))

structure(list(id2 = c(1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4), adm2 = c("2014/08/29", 
"2014/09/08", "2006/08/31", "2007/01/01", "2007/01/07", "2007/01/08"
), disc2 = c("2014/09/08", "2006/08/31", "2006/08/31", "2007/01/07", 
"2007/01/08", "2005/07/03")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-6L))
```

Comment: two different criteria for different patients??  In first you have retained second date of admn, whereas in another patient you have retained first date of discharge

Comment: sorry I made a mistake there. I made the changes. If the next admission date is less than the previous discharge date then make them equal. It will create a same admission and discharge.

Answer (score 1):

```r
df <- structure(list(id = c(1, 1, 2, 2), adm = c("2006/06/14", "2006/08/23", 
                                           "2007/01/01", "2007/01/03"), disc = c("2006/08/31", "2006/08/31", 
                                                                                 "2007/01/07", "2007/01/08")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
                                                                                                                                                   -4L))
library(dplyr, warn.conflicts = F)

df %>% group_by(id) %>%
  mutate(across(c(adm, disc), as.Date)) %>%
  mutate(adm = if_else(adm < lag(disc, default = first(adm)), lag(disc), adm))
#> # A tibble: 4 x 3
#> # Groups:   id [2]
#>      id adm        disc      
#>   <dbl> <date>     <date>    
#> 1     1 2006-06-14 2006-08-31
#> 2     1 2006-08-31 2006-08-31
#> 3     2 2007-01-01 2007-01-07
#> 4     2 2007-01-07 2007-01-08
```

<sup>Created on 2021-07-08 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

Comment: This works on my sample data but in my actual data I think for some reasons the group_by(id) is not working as I got discharged date which is greater than the admission date for the next patient is assigned.

Comment: @kamrankhan please revise your data so that problem can be understood better

Comment: It worked. The issue was that I had plyr package loaded as well which after detaching and then using dplyr worked perfectly.